# Does AngularStrap Select work with angular-translator?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, bootstrap-select, angular-translate

I'm using AngularStrap Select with angular-translate to translate the select title. The problem is when I select other language, the select title doesn't change, only when I refresh the page, but not when I press the button to change the language.

An example is below:

```
<select bs-select ng-model="day">
   <option value="0">{{'DAY' | translate}}</option>
   <option ng-repeat="day in days" value="{{day}}">{{day}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried with $(element).selectpicker('refresh') and $compile too, but nothing doesn't work.

Comment: could you provide a plunk that shows that issue, so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error today, that the translations were not yet loaded when the directive read the `data-placeholder` attribute. Translation of the options are also affected, unless I specify data-html="1". My current workaround is like this.

In controller:

```
function setTranslated() {
    var removeListener = $rootScope.$on('$translateLoadingEnd', function () {
        vm.translated = true;
        removeListener();
        removeListener = null;
    });
}
```

In HTML, note the `ng-if`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="vm.query.states" 
ng-options="state.value as state.value|translate for state in vm.stateOptions" 
data-placeholder="{{'SELECT_STATE'|translate}}" 
data-multiple="1" bs-select ng-if="vm.translated"></button>
```